# Read from NSDictionary to NSMutableArray Crash when there's only one element

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have a NSDictionary that I get data from a xml file.

The xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<root>
<customer>
    <areas>
        <area>
            <company>ABC</company>
            <state>OO</state>
            <area_name>Somename</area_name>
            <count>123</count>
            <total_custs>123123</total_custs>
        </area>
       <area>
            <company>BCD</company>
            <state>EE</state>
            <area_name>Somename2</area_name>
            <count>1233</count>
            <total_custs>11233</total_custs>
        </area>
    </areas>
</customer>
</root>
```

I read this xml into a `NSDictionary`, say `myDict`, then I want to store it in a `NSMutableArray`, say `myArray`, I use:

```
myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[[[myDict objectForKey:@"root"] objectForKey:@""customer"] objectForKey:@"areas"] objectForKey:@"area"]] autorelease];
```

This works fine if I have **zero, or two or more** `<area>`, but it crash if I have only one, just like what I showed above.

Here are some information that I think might be helpful,

```
2011-08-12 09:04:40.343 TEST[28595:ef03] -[__NSCFDictionary getObjects:range:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x588af50
2011-08-12 09:04:40.345 TEST[28595:ef03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary getObjects:range:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x588af50'
```

Part of the call stack:

```
0   CoreFoundation                      0x011fc5a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01350313 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x011fe0bb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
3   CoreFoundation                      0x0116d966 ___forwarding___ + 966
4   CoreFoundation                      0x0116d522 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
5   CoreFoundation                      0x011f7fc5 -[NSArray initWithArray:range:copyItems:] + 245
6   CoreFoundation                      0x0115fdc0 -[NSArray initWithArray:] + 96
```

EDIT:

I think I might just have a clue what's going on, so I add a if-else statement like that:

```
if ([[[[[myDict objectForKey:@"root"] objectForKey:@""customer"] objectForKey:@"areas"] objectForKey:@"area"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    ALog(@"is array!");
}
else
{
    ALog(@"not array!");
}
```

When there's only one element, it gives me "no array", but I'm still using `initWithArray` to crate my NSMutableArray.

So I can check if a object is or isn't a type using `isKindOfClass`, is there a way for it to just tell me what kind of object it is?

Comment: can you include the code of where and how your are populating myDict dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say how you've translated the XML to a dictionary, but both from the structure of your XML and from the error, `area` appears to be an dictionary, not an array, so you can't use it as the argument to `initWithArray:`. Presumably your mapping from XML to objects is turning it into an array of dictionaries when there are many `area` elements but not when there's only one.

Comment: Thanks! I solve this in the noon but didn't get a chance to update. It turns into **array of NSDictioinary** when there're multiple, but **NSDictionary** when there's only one. I used `isKindOfClass` to determine and assign accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try breaking up your calls into different lines to see where the error is happening.

Instead of this:

```
myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[[[myDict objectForKey:@"root"] objectForKey:@""customer"] objectForKey:@"areas"] objectForKey:@"area"]] autorelease];
```

Try this:

```
NSDictionary *root = [mydict objectForKey:@"root"];
NSDictionary *customer = [root objectForKey:@"customer"];
NSDictionary *areas = [customer objectForKey:@"areas"];
NSDictionary *area = [areas objectForKey:@"area"];
myArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: area] autorelease];
```

Comment: Since `[areas objectForKey:@"area"]` is not a NSDictionary, I remove the 4th line and changed the 5th to `myArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray[areas objectForKey:@"area"]] autorelease];`, and that's where it crash. So now I have to figure out when there's only one element, when I do `[areas objectForKey:@"area"]`, what kind of object do I get so that I can init my array accordingly.

Comment: I think it is crashing because areas is an array and you are trying to call `[areas objectForKey:@"area"]` on it, which is an `NSDictionary` method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually a little surprised that it works for 2 or more `<area>` nodes. When you have more than one area, wouldn't your code put all the individual `<area>` nodes in an array? So when you try to call `[areas objectForKey:@"area"]` it should crash because areas is an `NSArray`, not an `NSDictionary`. It wouldn't make sense that it is a dictionary because it can't have duplicate keys. So if it is, then it is overwriting the value stored in the `area` key if there is more than one.

I have a suspicion that your code is reversed somewhere - it is putting the `<area>` nodes in a dictionary if there is 2 or more (causing some overwriting) and putting them in an array if there is only 1 (causing the crash for calling a method that `NSArray` doesn't hvave), but it is supposed to do the opposite.